# Spring Security With Custom Login Flow

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I am trying to add spring with spring security in an existing Struts based application. It is a Partial migration. All the new development should happen in Spring.

So what I want is,

- User access a Secured URL
- If the user is not authenticated Spring Should redirect to a specific URL (This will be a Struts URL)
- After Old Struts Module does its work of authenticating the user, It saves an Object in HTTP Session which depicts the authenticated User.
- Spring Should get this Object from Session and Authenticated the User.
- Redirect the User to the requested Secured URL

I have tried to used `formlogin().loginpage(<Struts_URL>)`. Also in the Struts code after authentication, I have updated the Spring's `SecurityContext`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity pHttp) throws Exception
    {
        pHttp.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/<Struts_Login_Entry>.do");
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity pWeb) throws Exception 
    {
        // All the Strtus URL has .do suffix so excluding it
        pWeb.ignoring().antMatchers("/*.do", "/portal/**");
    }
}
```

After Authentication in Struts

```
...
MyUserDetails lUserDetails = new MyUserDetails(pUserName, pRole);
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(lUserDetails, null, lUserDetails.getAuthorities());
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
securityContext.setAuthentication(auth);
...
```

The User is getting redirected to Struts page when he accesses any Spring URL But this happens even if the user is authenticated.

I am not so familiar with Spring Security, any suggestion or help?